# Hemiptera sp preimago?

Tags: species-identification, entomology, ecology, hemiptera

Which species of Hemiptera is this preimago, seen in 2015 in Rome?

[image]

Comment: Can you please download the image from flickr and upload it here? You can credit flickr and the photographer.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I am the photographer. Can you help me identifying this species? Thank you again! Elena

Comment: @Elena You should add the picture here. And you should edit the question to add details such as geographical location, environment type, climate, habitat or whatever you can tell about the organism. Have a look at other [tag:species-identification] questions.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is an [Aphid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aphid#Anatomy) because it has long, thin legs and two-jointed, two-clawed tarsi and resemble the Russian wheat aphid very much. They are very common in temperate zone and is a major plant pest.

Here's how the Russian wheat aphid looks:
[image]

Source:[Website of tasmanian government](http://dpipwe.tas.gov.au/biosecurity/plant-biosecurity/pests-and-diseases/russian-wheat-aphid-(rwa))